Facing Google Restrictions on Time Based Triggers every 5 minutes
Could you please  confirm if real-time syncing, with Gmail activities and attachments updating every 5 minutes, is achievable using a 5-minute time-based trigger in Apps Script?
The primary goal was to enable Gmail activities (such as new messages and attachments) to sync with Dynamics 365 leads as close to real-time as possible like every minute or 5 minutes with API from appsscript.
As Google Workspace Add-ons restrict time-based triggers to a minimum interval of one hour. For add-ons, can we make interval between time-based triggers down to 5,10 minutes?

This is not a question about a practícal specific problem that is unique to programming. Please add more details like your estimation of the daily trigger total execution time. Better if you also adds a [mcve]

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Time-driven Trigger on Workspace add-ons
Based on the public documentation of Time-driven triggers of Google workspace, it's stated that An add-on can use a time-driven trigger once per hour at most.Therefore, I am afraid that it wouldn't be possible to achieve your goal. Furthermore, please keep in mind the following information provided in the documentation that may answer your question about real-time syncing.

The time might be slightly randomized—for example, if you create a
recurring 9 AM trigger, Apps Script chooses a time between 9 AM and 10
AM, then keeps that timing consistent from day to day so that 24 hours
elapse before the trigger fires again.

Reference: Time-driven Trigger
